# What is the Big O complexity of Autoboxing

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I know that we always talk about a performance hit when autoboxing, but I would like to know if that affects the Big O complexity of an algorithm.

The Java implementation of the constructor for the Character class is :

```
public Character(char value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

The constructor is constant time so it really comes down to object creation.  Would object creation affect Big O time?  For instance if you are putting the chars of a `String` into a `HashSet<Character>` would that still be O(n) where n is the # of chars in the String?

Comment: I don't see why boxing or unboxing would change the complexity.  Why do you think it would?

Comment: Boxing is a constant-time operation.

Comment: I'd expect unboxing to be cheap, but autoboxing can be expensive because it's constructing a new object, so if it's done multiple times in a loop there could be a serious penalty. That said, I agree with Tim, since both autoboxing/unboxing requires a constant number of operations, it shouldn't effect the overall big O.

Comment: I assumed it is a constant time operation, but because I read how expensive it can be I wanted to know how it would look to present a solution to an algorithm that has autoboxing involved.

Comment: "For instance if you are putting the chars of a String into a HashSet would that still be O(n) where n is the # of chars in the String?" -- that's not something that autoboxing does. Why are you bringing this up?

Comment: Right, I think the OP doesn't mean "complexity," I think they're asking what value do they use when computing the complexity.  I'm not sure myself, but while Java object creation is relatively fast, it isn't as fast as say integer arithmetic.  I'd count it as about 50x the time for one integer addition, but it could be around 100x or more.

Comment: And of course the best way to determine this would be to actually micro-benchmark some code and see what sort of time you actually measure.

Comment: @markspace I may be misunderstanding you, but a "value" is irrelevant when computing complexity. O((10^100)n) equals O(n).

Comment: 1. Autoboxing is*O(1)*. 2. Putting the chars of a String into a HashSet has exactly nothing to do with autoboxing.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt For Big-O that's true, you're right.  I think though the OP might want the actual running time (and that "Big O" in the title might be a mistake), and knowing all the terms in that equation would be needed in that case

Comment: This may be a subtly tricky question. I think most machine models can reasonably assume allocations are basically constant time, but really that is a simplification of the real truth. Heap allocations, paging, etc. - at the end of the day calling that constant time is as idealized as saying a hash table is constant time.

Comment: There is no point in any of this second-guessing about what the OP means. He has explicitly used the term 'Big-O complexity', several times, and, until he states otherwise, that is what question is about. Let's stick to the stated topic please.

Comment: It should also mentioned that the question contains a confusion as to what *N* is: the size of the set, or the length of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I did indeed mean Big O complexity, but because there does seem to be some hidden costs to object creation I wanted another's opinion rather than my own assumption.  @EJP n is the size of the string as it states in the question, and in order to put the chars of a String into a Hashset<Character> you must autobox (or explicitly create) from char to Character b/c collections cannot contain primitive types.

Comment: @LuckyB Right, so calculating the hash is *O(N)* in the length of the string, and autoboxing being *O(1)* doesn't change that in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No.  It does not change the complexity.

The complexity of autoboxing a single value is `O(1)` in all cases.  The cost of adding a single element to a HashSet is `O(1)` amortized, on average.  The cost of doing the two things at once is still `O(1)` on average.

---

The actual cost of adding an element to a `HashSet` is highly variable.  The variability is due to two things:

- Hash collisions due to poor hash function choice or "bad luck", can cause the `HashSet` to search long hash chains.  In the worst case, that can be `O(N)`.  For your example, these things don't apply<sup>1</sup>.
- If the number of elements in a `HashSet` grows continually, it will periodically need to reallocate its hash array and recreate the hash chains.  However, since the `HashSet` algorithms double the array size each time, the amortized overhead doesn't alter the `O(1)` average cost per insertion.

The actual cost of autoboxing is also variable.  For some primitives, the corresponding Wrapper type maintains a cache of previously instantiated autoboxed values for a subset of the primitive value range.  If `valueOf(prim)` gives a cache hit, then no new object is allocated.

For your example, `Character` caches boxed values for U0000 through U007F.

---

Someone mentioned that the cost of memory allocation is not necessarily `O(1)`.  That is technically true.  However, in order to achieve worse than `O(1)` behavior you need some bad things to be happening; e.g.

- A heap that is too close to full, leading to poor GC ergonomics.
- A heap that is using too much of the available physical memory and causing VM thrashing.
- (On a multi-core system) too many threads trying to access too many different areas of the heap at the same time, leading to h/w level memory cache contention and pipeline stalls.

The solutions to these problems tend to be to increase heap sizes, buy more memory, get a beefier machine ... or redesign your algorithms.

---

<sup>1 - Worst-case behavior is `O(N)`only occurs with poor hash functions and / or  unfortunate element patterns.  The former cannot happen for primitive wrappers: look at the implementation of `Character::hashCode()` for example.  The latter cannot happen because `Character` implements `Comparable`.</sup>